# MX960 port mirroring only Tx or Rx side

Tags: networking, juniper

On Cisco routers there is an option to do port mirroring only on Rx or Tx side, by using this command:

> monitor session session_number source interface interface-id [, | -]
>   **[both | rx | tx]**
>
> (Optional) Specify the direction of traffic to monitor. If you do not
>   specify a traffic direction, the source interface sends both sent and
>   received traffic.
>
> - both - Monitor both received and sent traffic
> - rx - Monitor received traffic
> - tx - Monitor sent traffic.

Is there a similar configuration on a Juniper MX960?

Answer (score 1):

Its possible.

In case link below breaks sometime in future.

Browse to Configuring Layer 2 Port Mirroring at MX Series Config Guide on [Juniper  Documentation Page](https://www.juniper.net/techpubs/).

[Follow this Config Guide](http://www.juniper.net/techpubs/en_US/junos10.0/information-products/topic-collections/config-guide-mx-series-layer2/jd0e2431.html).

Comment: Please can you give more details about what is found at the other end of the link, in case it stops working in future.

Answer (score 0):

The MX may have different limitations, but on EX series switches I follow this:

http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB21200&cat=JUNOS_EX&actp=LIST

You can choose ingress and egress separately to monitor.

This may help too: http://forums.juniper.net/t5/Junos-and-Junosphere/MX960-L3-Port-Mirroring/td-p/17063

And this one looks most promising: http://forums.juniper.net/t5/Routing/MX-port-mirror/td-p/72956

Comment: Thanks For the answer, from the links I didn't actually saw the option to configure Tx / Rx mirroring seperatly in the MX960 if you understood this differently can you please point me to the configuration you saw, Thanks again for the support

Comment: just notice the following int he last link filter {
                    output egress-portmirror;   is that what you meant ?

Comment: well the output filter in that case goes to the analyzer ports.... on the other end though, you would have a filter for ingress, and for egress, or just one.